# Make UIActivityViewController present every system action with iOS 12 modal style

Tags: iphone, ios13, uiactivityviewcontroller

iOS 13 changed modal presentation style. So now I need my share controller to display every system action like send an e-mail with text or open system messages vc with old iOS 12 modal style. Here is how I make the thing

```
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text], applicationActivities: nil)

if UIDevice.isIPad, let popover = activityVC.popoverPresentationController {
    popover.sourceRect = self.view.bounds
    popover.sourceView = self.view
    popover.permittedArrowDirections = [.up]
}

self.present(activityVC, animated: true)
```

Doesn't matter what modalPresentationStyle I'm setting. At best it affects activityVC. But every system VC opened from it goes back to new modal style. And I see some apps which present those screens in old style. Extremely confused here...

Surprisingly I can't find anyone asking that or similar questions. Everything is usually about just other VCs.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using NavigationControllerView, try the snippet below in viewDidLoad() of RootViewController. Hope this works for you.

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    isModalPresentation = true
} else {
// 
}
```